# Trying to put a search functionality in my application

Tags: android, search

Hi, guys! First of all, I'm newbie! I'm trying to create a search functionality (Search BY CITY) in my application. But something is wrong! It don't work!

The error message is: 'The method filter(String) is undefined for the type BinderData'

```
                adapter.filter(text);
```

Could someone help me in details? I included the "TextWatcher" function in my  main activity (WeatherActivity).

This is my code:

WeatherActivity

```
public class WeatherActivity extends Activity {

// XML node keys
static final String KEY_TAG = "weatherdata"; // parent node
static final String KEY_ID = "id";
static final String KEY_CITY = "city";
static final String KEY_TEMP_C = "tempc";
static final String KEY_TEMP_F = "tempf";
static final String KEY_CONDN = "condition";
static final String KEY_SPEED = "windspeed";
static final String KEY_ICON = "icon";
EditText editsearch;
// List items 
ListView list;
BinderData adapter = null;
List<HashMap<String,String>> weatherDataCollection;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    try {


        DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = docBuilder.parse (getAssets().open("weatherdata.xml"));










        weatherDataCollection = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

        // normalize text representation
        doc.getDocumentElement ().normalize ();

        NodeList weatherList = doc.getElementsByTagName("weatherdata");

        HashMap<String,String> map = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < weatherList.getLength(); i++) {

               map = new HashMap<String,String>(); 

               Node firstWeatherNode = weatherList.item(i);

                if(firstWeatherNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){

                    Element firstWeatherElement = (Element)firstWeatherNode;
                    //-------
                    NodeList idList = firstWeatherElement.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ID);
                    Element firstIdElement = (Element)idList.item(0);
                    NodeList textIdList = firstIdElement.getChildNodes();
                    //--id
                    map.put(KEY_ID, ((Node)textIdList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());

                    //2.-------
                    NodeList cityList = firstWeatherElement.getElementsByTagName(KEY_CITY);
                    Element firstCityElement = (Element)cityList.item(0);
                    NodeList textCityList = firstCityElement.getChildNodes();
                    //--city
                    map.put(KEY_CITY, ((Node)textCityList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());

                    //3.-------
                    NodeList tempList = firstWeatherElement.getElementsByTagName(KEY_TEMP_C);
                    Element firstTempElement = (Element)tempList.item(0);
                    NodeList textTempList = firstTempElement.getChildNodes();
                    //--city
                    map.put(KEY_TEMP_C, ((Node)textTempList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());

                    //4.-------
                    NodeList condList = firstWeatherElement.getElementsByTagName(KEY_CONDN);
                    Element firstCondElement = (Element)condList.item(0);
                    NodeList textCondList = firstCondElement.getChildNodes();
                    //--city
                    map.put(KEY_CONDN, ((Node)textCondList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());

                    //5.-------
                    NodeList speedList = firstWeatherElement.getElementsByTagName(KEY_SPEED);
                    Element firstSpeedElement = (Element)speedList.item(0);
                    NodeList textSpeedList = firstSpeedElement.getChildNodes();
                    //--city
                    map.put(KEY_SPEED, ((Node)textSpeedList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());

                    //6.-------
                    NodeList iconList = firstWeatherElement.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ICON);
                    Element firstIconElement = (Element)iconList.item(0);
                    NodeList textIconList = firstIconElement.getChildNodes();
                    //--city
                    map.put(KEY_ICON, ((Node)textIconList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());

                    //Add to the Arraylist
                    weatherDataCollection.add(map);
            }       
        }


        BinderData bindingData = new BinderData(this,weatherDataCollection);






        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        adapter = new BinderData(WeatherActivity.this,
                weatherDataCollection);



   editsearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);

        editsearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String text = editsearch.getText().toString()
                    .toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
            adapter.filter(text);
        }

    });




        Log.i("BEFORE", "<<------------- Before SetAdapter-------------->>");

        list.setAdapter(bindingData);

        Log.i("AFTER", "<<------------- After SetAdapter-------------->>");









        // Click event for single list row
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setClass(WeatherActivity.this, SampleActivity.class);

                // parameters
                i.putExtra("position", String.valueOf(position + 1));

                /* selected item parameters
                 * 1.   City name
                 * 2.   Weather
                 * 3.   Wind speed
                 * 4.   Temperature
                 * 5.   Weather icon   
                 */
                i.putExtra("city", weatherDataCollection.get(position).get(KEY_CITY));
                i.putExtra("weather", weatherDataCollection.get(position).get(KEY_CONDN));
                i.putExtra("windspeed", weatherDataCollection.get(position).get(KEY_SPEED));
                i.putExtra("temperature", weatherDataCollection.get(position).get(KEY_TEMP_C));
                i.putExtra("icon", weatherDataCollection.get(position).get(KEY_ICON));

                // start the sample activity
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

    }

    catch (IOException ex) {
        Log.e("Error", ex.getMessage());
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e("Error", "Loading exception");
    }
}








@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

BlinderData

```
public class BinderData extends BaseAdapter {

// XML node keys
static final String KEY_TAG = "weatherdata"; // parent node
static final String KEY_ID = "id";
static final String KEY_CITY = "city";
static final String KEY_TEMP_C = "tempc";
static final String KEY_TEMP_F = "tempf";
static final String KEY_CONDN = "condition";
static final String KEY_SPEED = "windspeed";
static final String KEY_ICON = "icon";

LayoutInflater inflater;
ImageView thumb_image;
List<HashMap<String,String>> weatherDataCollection;
ViewHolder holder;
public BinderData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public BinderData(Activity act, List<HashMap<String,String>> map) {

    this.weatherDataCollection = map;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) act
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}


public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//      return idlist.size();
    return weatherDataCollection.size();
}

public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null){

      vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
      holder = new ViewHolder();

      holder.tvCity = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.tvCity); // city name
      holder.tvWeather = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.tvCondition); // city weather overview
      holder.tvTemperature =  (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.tvTemp); // city temperature
      holder.tvWeatherImage =(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image); // thumb image

      vi.setTag(holder);
    }
    else{

        holder = (ViewHolder)vi.getTag();
    }

      // Setting all values in listview

      holder.tvCity.setText(weatherDataCollection.get(position).get(KEY_CITY));
      holder.tvWeather.setText(weatherDataCollection.get(position).get(KEY_CONDN));
      holder.tvTemperature.setText(weatherDataCollection.get(position).get(KEY_TEMP_C));

      //Setting an image
      String uri = "drawable/"+ weatherDataCollection.get(position).get(KEY_ICON);
      int imageResource = vi.getContext().getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, vi.getContext().getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
      Drawable image = vi.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
      holder.tvWeatherImage.setImageDrawable(image);

      return vi;
}

/*
 * 
 * */
static class ViewHolder{

    TextView tvCity;
    TextView tvTemperature;
    TextView tvWeather;
    ImageView tvWeatherImage;
}

}
```

SampleActivity

```
public class SampleActivity extends Activity {

String position = "1";
String city = "";
String weather = "";
String temperature = "";
String windSpeed = "";
String iconfile = "";
ImageButton imgWeatherIcon;

TextView tvcity;
TextView tvtemp;
TextView tvwindspeed;
TextView tvCondition;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.detailpage);

    try {

        //handle for the UI elements 
        imgWeatherIcon = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonAlpha);
        //Text fields
        tvcity = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewCity);
        tvtemp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTemperature);
        tvwindspeed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewWindSpeed);
        tvCondition = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewCondition);

        // Get position to display
        Intent i = getIntent();

        this.position = i.getStringExtra("position");
        this.city = i.getStringExtra("city");
        this.weather=   i.getStringExtra("weather");
        this.temperature =  i.getStringExtra("temperature");
        this.windSpeed =  i.getStringExtra("windspeed");
        this.iconfile = i.getStringExtra("icon");

        String uri = "drawable/"+ "d" + iconfile;
        int imageBtnResource = getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, getPackageName());
        Drawable dimgbutton = getResources().getDrawable(imageBtnResource);


        //text elements
        tvcity.setText(city);
        tvtemp.setText(temperature);
        tvwindspeed.setText(windSpeed);
        tvCondition.setText(weather);

        //thumb_image.setImageDrawable(image);
        imgWeatherIcon.setImageDrawable(dimgbutton);


    }

    catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e("Error", "Loading exception");
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

XParser

```
public class XParser extends DefaultHandler {

ArrayList<String> idlist = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> citylist = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> condilist = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> templist = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> speedlist = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> iconlist = new ArrayList<String>();

//temp variable to store the data chunk read while parsing 
private String tempStore    =   null;

public XParser() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/*
 * Clears the tempStore variable on every start of the element
 * notification
 * 
 * */
public void startElement (String uri, String localName, String qName,
           Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

    super.startElement(uri, localName, qName, attributes);

    if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("id")) {
        tempStore = "";
    } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("city")) {
        tempStore = "";
    } 
    else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("tempc")) {
        tempStore = "";
    }
    else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("condition")) {
        tempStore = "";
    }
    else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("windspeed")) {
        tempStore = "";
    }
    else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("icon")) {
        tempStore = "";
    }
    else {
        tempStore = "";
    }
}

/*
 * updates the value of the tempStore variable into
 * corresponding list on receiving end of the element
 * notification
 * */
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
        throws SAXException {
    super.endElement(uri, localName, qName);

    if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("id")) {
        idlist.add(tempStore);
    } 
    else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("city")) {
        citylist.add(tempStore);
    }
    else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("tempc")) {
        templist.add(tempStore);
    }
    else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("condition")) {
        condilist.add(tempStore);
    }
    else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("windspeed")) {
        speedlist.add(tempStore);
    }
    else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("icon")) {
        iconlist.add(tempStore);
    }

    tempStore = "";
}

/*
 * adds the incoming data chunk of character data to the 
 * temp data variable - tempStore
 * 
 * */
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
        throws SAXException {
    super.characters(ch, start, length);
    tempStore += new String(ch, start, length);
}

}``










@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}


}
```

Comment: You've posted quite a bit of source code here. You should try to trim it down to a simpler program that still displays the problem. And you need to describe what's wrong in more detail. Just saying that it doesn't work isn't very helpful. What does it do that it shoudn't? What is it failing to do that it should do?

Comment: @Kenster OK! It should search by City, but it doesn't work. Now, I put the error message above.